# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Website

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I had a genius idea today to try and create a website that would access our CRM database and will report on support cases.

The idea would be to have a page that would be visible in the office and members of the support team can view the current status of support cases.

I've downloaded the CRM SDK and I've read a couple of manuals, but I can't seem to find a decent starting point for a complete rookie..

Are there are good tutorials out there on how to create a website that will communicate with CRM's database, preferrably for a VB.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several products that implement your idea.
The most famous one is the Adxstudio, you can find a community edition (also for CRM 4.0) at this address:

http://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/

After you can check the source code, but they use C#

Comment: Thank you @GuidoPreite, I'll take a look.

I've kind of been learning C# by converting it into VB aha, so I should be okay with that.